# What is the best way to share a database connection between forms in C#?

Tags: c#, database, forms, oracle, parent-child

I have a main window form which opens many other forms. All forms have a common oracle database connection.

I new to C# (have been using visual basic up until now) and I am not sure the best way to achieve this.

Potential options:

1. Pass the connection to the child form as input.
2. Pass the main window form to the child form as parent and use its member variable connection.
3. Some other option I haven't considered.

Edit: see @C4ud3x 's answer for an example class to perform the functionality.

Comment: Connection's [are already pooled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502(v=vs.110).aspx) you should not be passing them around, open one, use it for a single query, then dispose it as soon as you can for best performance.

Comment: Are you really talking about sharing `ONE` connection? Why not adding a new class like `database.cs`, declaring an `open -> command -> close` process and using it from all forms?

Comment: @C4ud3x Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: @confused_programmer I've posted an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option 3:

Don't share connections.  Don't keep connections open for multiple requests (unless they are  *immediately* after each other in code).  Don't expose connections as public properties.

Connections are pooled by .NET, so creating them isn't an expensive process.  Create a connection when you need it, use it, then dispose of it.  An effective way of doing that is with `using` blocks.

If you want a central place to store a connection *string* that is used to *create* the connection that's fine - you can use app.config or some other mechanism to store *that* in one place.

Comment: Do you really think hes talking about passing the connection rather than sharing the structure of opening a connection?

Comment: @C4ud3x Yes I do.  That's what the question states.  "Pass the connection...", "...use its member variable connection."  Plus, other platforms may not pool connections like .NET does, so sharing them may offer _some_ benefits in those platforms.

Comment: For some extra reading, here is a link to the MSDN page on [Oracle connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: This is great information. I am rebuilding a project I did not write. Previously, he shared connections between the whole program and left them open.

Comment: @confused_programmer Unfortunately it's not uncommon.  It _may_ not hurt anything, but you have to add a lot of checking to see if the connection is already open, deal with exceptions, etc. that you don't need to do if you aren't sharing the object around.  So if it ain't broke, don't fix it, but if you're redoing code anyways I'd highly recommend that you not continue that practice.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing connections is very dangerous. If you want to do it anyway, here is a possible way:
You could define an interface an pass this one. This way, you could define other properties to share later on.

```
public interface IMainWindow
{
  Datebase Db;
}
```

Implement this interface to your MainWindow:

```
public Window MainWindow : IMainWindow
{
  public Database Db
 ...
}
```

You second Window accessing the MainWindow only thorught this interface.

```
public Window SecondWindow
{
  private readonly IMainWindow Mw;
  public SecondWindow(IMainWindow Mw)
  {
    this.Mw = Mw;
    //Access the MainWindow database with Mw.Db
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the connection and let them share but that is not the recommended practice.  If one form forgets to close or handle an exception then it effects all forms.   If you progress to parallel or background processing then connection could be in use.

You do need to share the connection string. This could be a shared variable of pass it to the form in the ctor.

```
Connection con = new Connection(conString);
try 
{
   con.Open();
   Command cmd = con.CreateCommand();
   // use command 
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
}
finally 
{
   con.Close();
}
```

Open and Close are very fast.  The recommend practice is Open as late as possible and Close as soon as possible to keep number of connections down.

Yes you can wrap all that in a database type class but I like just using is directly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the instructions about `whats wrong with your question` you could add a new class for the database stuff and access it from all forms like this:

```
// database.cs
public static class Database
{
    static string connectionString = "user=...pass=...db=...etc";

    public static void ExecuteQuery(string query)
    {
        // open connection
        // send query
        // close connection
    }
}

// form1.cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        Database.ExecuteQuery("Select something");
    }
}

// form2.cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void anotherOne()
    {
        Database.ExecuteQuery("Update something");
    }
}
```

In this case you wouldnt need to declare variables in all of your forms or pass instances of anything.

Also you would just need to care about a clean `open -> send -> close` process one time for your application.